# How to hide a field in django modelform?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

For example:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    ref1 = models.ForeignKey(RefModel)
    text1 = models.TextField()

class TestModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ('text1')
```

I only allow the user to input **text1** field, but when I redefine the *post method* of my view, I also want to set the **ref1** value, how should I do that?

I wish I can let TestModelForm has the ref1 field but don't let user modify it, then I can modify the value of request.POSt in post method, and pass it to TestModelForm, is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want to include it in the form at all if the user can't modify it? You have the right idea of setting it in the view. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: @DanielRoseman For example, I want the website to auto generate the ref1 field according to the url the user is accessing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `HiddenInput` as `ref1` widget:

```
class TestModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        widgets = {
            'ref1': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

Another option is saving form with `commit` argument equal `False`. This way you can include only visible fields in form and then update model instance with needed data:

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            ref = get_ref_according_to_url()
            instance.ref1 = ref
            instance.save()
            # ...
```

Comment: Finally someone made this thing clear enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** I am using (Django 3.2)

I tried to add a widget and it did not work for me, but I solved it in a simpler way without using widgets.

```
class TestModelForm(ModelForm):
    ref1 = forms.CharField (widget = forms.Textarea(
        attrs = {
            'hidden': '',
        }
    ))
```

I hope this helps you or others ;)