# Django DateTimeField hide date

Tags: django

I have a model where an object is called `time` which is `model.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)`

I also have a form where the user can specify the `time`, but I wanted to only have the H: M in there, not the whole datetime.

I tried using the TimeInput widget in my form, but that would give me an error upon submitting because I didn't have the 'date' portion of the `DateTimeField`. If I use `models.TimeField` for `time`, I lose the ability to keep track of the date in the admin page.

How can I hide the date from showing in my form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a field in django modelform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606786/how-to-hide-a-field-in-django-modelform)

Comment: @Philip Adler 

Isn't that hiding one of many fields while 'DateTimeField' is a field by itself?

Comment: I tried forms.HiddenInput('%Y-%m-%d') but it gives me attrs= attrs.copy -> 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: sorry, the duplicate message doesn't allow the custom addition of "have them as separate fields but keep one hidden", but I see you figured that one out for yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

Worked around the problem by having one model as DateTimeField and another as TimeField.